# Visually divide the numbers by type 1,000,000 in AppCompatEditText

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I have such a task: there is an AppCompatEditText and I need to make it so that I can only enter numbers and the written text is immediately visually divided by this type: 1,000,000, 2,500, etc.

I tried to do it like this through TextWatcher:

```
...
val text = s.toString().replace(",", "").replace(" ", "")
        try {
            val formattedText = decimalFormat.format(text.toLong())
            editText.setText(formattedText)
            editText.setSelection(formattedText.length)
        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
...
```

but it doesn't work. Please help me! :(